# Core-Plot CPTRangePlot filled area is distorted when scrolling (iOS)

Tags: ios, zooming, core-plot, fill

Recently I have encountered a strange behavior from CPTRangePlot (I'm using Core-Plot 1.3).

I have a set of 365 data to display on the screen using CPTRangePlot. It works fine if all 365 points are displayed on the screen.

However, if I zoom in by using plotSpace:willChangePlotRangeTo:forCoordinate method to a certain level, the fill area will be distorted and the plot will be filled incorrectly. If I scroll to another plot range, the distorted area becomes fine and but another distorted area appears.

Everything goes back to normal if I zoom out.

Here are the images for your reference:

Before Zoom in:

[image]

After Zoom in:

[image]

Any idea what happening here? All other plot types (Scatter, Trading, Bar) work fine when I zoom in/out or scroll :-(

P/S: I tried the latest version of Core-Plot (1.4+) but no success.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a Core Plot bug—it is skipping points that fall outside the visible area when drawing the fill. Please report this on the Core Plot [issue tracker](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/issues).